# Mail php function getting error in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using mail function to override reset password auth.

```
public function resetPassword(Request $request){
    $new_password = rand(120400, 940490);
    $email=$request->input("email");
    $user = new User();
    $count = $user -> where('email',$email) -> count();
    if ($count == 0){
        $meta = $api_meta->metaData(false,"Email does not exist.",[],'');
        return ['meta'=>$meta];
    }
    $user = $user -> where('email',$email) -> get() -> first();


    $user -> password = bcrypt($new_password);
    $user -> save();

    $to      = $email;
    $subject = 'user message';
    $message = "
    Your new password is : $new_password
    ";
    $headers = 'From: ' .$email. "\r\n";


    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

}

In Router.php I modified from :

```
$this->post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
```

to:

```
$this->post('password/email', 'UserController@resetPassword')->name('password.email');
```

I think everything there is alright but I get an error :

> Cannot send message without a sender address

Comment: You should debug the arguments for `mail()`.

Comment: You should *stop using* `mail()`. Laravel has perfectly good Mail classes, why not use them?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've defined `from` in the `config/mail.php`:

```
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
],
```

If you didn't edit it, add sender email and name to the `.env`:

```
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=me@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=MyName
```

Comment: Since I'm using mail() function, is this needded ?

Comment: I did : $headers = 'From: ' .$email. "\r\n";

Comment: @xamarinDev you can get this error only when you use Laravel functionality to send an email (Swift).

Comment: So, is there any solution ?

Comment: @xamarinDev please show the full code of the controller method that is executed.

Comment: @xamarinDev looks like `Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail` is executed and tries to send an email with Swift. You've said you've modified `Router.php`. What exactly did you do?

Comment: Insted Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail , I use my function 'UserController@resetPassword' in UserController and trying sent email via mail()

Comment: @xamarinDev I understand that. Tell me what exactly did you do with standard auth routes. Did you edit `Router.php` or did something else?

Comment: I told I description, instead of buildin resetpassword method of laravel, I used my method in UserController.Only that